# tshark creates empty file when running from script

Tags: linux, csv, wireshark, pcap, tshark

i have written the following script to save csv file in a testcsv2 folder when a pcap file is generated in test2 folder

```
inotifywait -m /home/tejas/Desktop/test2 -e create |
 while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in dictionary '$path' via '$action'"
        tshark -r $file -T fields  -E separator=, -E occurrence=f  -e frame.time_epoch -e wlan.ta  -e tzsp.wlan.signal  > /home/tejas/Desktop/testcsv2/output.csv   
 done
```

However, when I run the tshark script from terminal it works fine but when I run this script it creates an empty file. What could be wrong?

EDIT: The following events occur when file is created

```
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ OPEN test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ MODIFY test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ OPEN,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ ACCESS,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ OPEN,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ ACCESS,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ ACCESS,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ ACCESS,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ MODIFY test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ MODIFY test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ MODIFY test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ MODIFY test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
/home/tejas/Desktop/test2/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE test_00052_20160830191016.pcap
```

Comment: (1) Inside the while loop, does `$file` exist, and does it have valid content? (2) You're matching on `create`. Maybe a different event would be more appropriate? If you just run `inotify` on the command line, what events are generated when a pcap file appears in that directory?

Comment: Yes , when I echo $file it returns the name of file. <2> I want to run this script only when new pcap file is generated , the pcap file is generated by tshark -i eno1 -f "udp port 37008" -b duration:30 -b files:10 -w /home/tejas/Desktop/test2/test.pcap

Comment: In (1), I meant "does the file referenced by `$file` exist, and does it have valid content?". I was not asking if the variable was defined.  It doesn't look like you've answered (2), which is specifically "exactly what inotify events are generated when that pcap file is generated".  Update your question with answers to those two items and I think we'll be able to provide more help.

Comment: @larsks sorry I am new to this. (1) Yes the file exists and its contents are valid.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the tip. I changed to match on different event and it worked.